# How to get the "value" of ng-href literally?! (leafy)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-bootstrap

How do i get the value of `pk` in the `ng-href` and how do i call it into my `controller.js`?

[image]

Comment: Please post the relevant code in the question itself, along with anything you have tried and explain what went wrong with it.  A link to an image is not a suitable question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: sorry guys :( i'll try to be specific next time

Comment: You can edit this question now - no need to wait till next time :)

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell you're using `ngRoute`, so in your module `app.js`, inject `ngRoute`, and `$routeProvider` in the config like so;

```
angular.module("app", ['ngRoute']).config(function($routeProvider){
})();
```

Then in the body of the configuration;

```
$routeProvider.when("/candidate/:pk", 
{
     controller: "controller",
     templateUrl: "htmlPage"
}
```

Now in your controller inject `$routeParams`, and then;

```
$scope.pk = $routeParams.pk;
```

In the future I recommend adding more code, so the question makes a bit more sense, I don't know exactly what you're doing so this is a pretty generic answer.